# How Can I Save Cookie File

Tags: php

I'm trying to login a website and grab cookie file. So I wrote a curl code with this lines;

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '\\cookies\\cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '\\cookies\\cookie.txt');
```

But it's not saving my file to directory. I can't see any problem so what can I do?

Comment: did you set proper permissions on your cookie file?

Comment: I'm working on localhost which permissions do you mentioned? Also that code works in main directory but when I try to specific directory, it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
```

instead of:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

Use an absolute path to the cookie jar file so that you're sure where it is saved and thus you know you have the right permission to write there.

curl stores all cookies it knows of to the file, including so called session cookies (that are without an expiry time)

solved the problem.